# Set layoutMargins using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, mapkit

I would like a map view that fills the screen but has its usable area restricted to the top half (via a bottom edge layout margin) and thus the bottom of the map extends underneath a visual effect view (which will contain a table) which is pinned to the bottom of the screen at half screen height. The same way it usually extends above and underneath toolbars.

To achieve this I can set the layoutMargins property in code as follows:

```
self.mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 0);
```

However I would like to do this with an auto-layout constraint instead, so that the margins are updated automatically due to the view size changing, for example due to a screen rotation. Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so how to add the particular layout constraint either in IB or in code? I believe it might require the use of NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

In the screenshot above, you can see the region has been set to the UK and fills the useable part of the map view, and you can also see the Legal label at bottom left is in the correct place. These are some of the benefits of using the layoutMargins property on the map view.

[image: Storyboard constraints]

Answer (score -1):

In Interface builder, simply pin the edges of your map view to the edges of your superview using a margin of 0. Then you could pin the sides and bottom of your Visual Effects view to the sides and bottom of the superview using a margin of 0. Then create a top constraint for the Visual Effects view (use whatever number is there. You're going to change it.)

Then in the inspector for your VFX views top constraint, you can change the "Second Item" to "Center Y". That means your top edge is now pinned to the center of the superviews vertical center.

This should keep the Visual Effects view always pinned to the bottom half of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't answer my problem. I don't have a problem pinning the effect view to the bottom half of the screen. I'm trying to pin the bottom layout margin of the map to the top edge of the visual effect view or its height.

Comment: My apologies, skimmed the question too quick. You can set the layout margins explicitly in IB under the Size Inspector, though it seems you're looking for something more dynamic. I would think about using size classes in a situation like this. Set the height explicitly in as many rotations as you need, and let the size classes handle the rotation and resizing.

Comment: I tried that setting but it doesn't have any effect, and yes I need the margin to be a constraint not an explicit value.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question! It seems it isn't possible to set a constraint in IB for layoutMargins, it is however possible to set User Defined Runtime Attributes by adding an entry for layoutMargins and use a type of CGRect and just put the bottom margin as the width param. However since we need a dynamic layout the solution is to put the following in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self viewWillTransitionToSize:self.view.bounds.size withTransitionCoordinator:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    self.mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, size.height/2.0, 0);
}
```

It seems bad to call a method with nil that takes a non-null param that calls also super but [Apple do it in this sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LookInside/Listings/LookInside_AAPLRootViewController_m.html).

There is one situation where this doesn't always work. If you switch too quickly from landscape to portrait and back again the margins don't get updated. However UIKit is full of bugs like this so just have to let it go.